# How to allow for specific domain access my style css in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

hello guys I'm trying to make a function to allow for specific users that I inserted to the table, to use my style CSS in laravel

my table example:

id: 1

name: user

domain: [www.userdomain.com](http://www.userdomain.com)

so where and how I can create a function to able to these domains in my table to use CSS file from my website?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you are trying to create a multi-themed and multi-domain site with Laravel. If you want to show different css files for each domain, you can add a ServiceProvider file for that job or just use AppServiceProvider, it's up to you. And get the theme or domain information from the database. There are many ways to then access this information in blade files.
You can access related information in blade files using View::share or with the help of bind / singleton commands for app() (application container).

One of the simpler ways would be to use ready-made libraries. https://github.com/qirolab/laravel-themer is quite successful.

There may be other shortcuts, but if the details are not considered, as the project grows it will be harder to maintain.